# Cluster index new cardinality operator disastrous estimation

Tags: sql-server, performance, clustered-index, sql-server-2019, cardinality

Recently we changed the Sql Server compatibility level from 110 (sql server 2012) to 150 (2019) after we migrated to Azure Managed instance a while back.

We're observing one query getting very very slow and times out. The query involves the following 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Workflow].[Transaction](
    [TransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [Workflow].[TransactionData](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [StateId] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Each Order transaction is kept in `[Workflow].[Transaction]`, 100M rows, the states through which a transaction passes, e.g. Started, InProgress, Successful, Failed, is kept in `[Workflow].[TransactionData]` 200M rows.

ClusterdIndex on [Workflow].[Transaction].StartDate, most of the times, queries are done based on a time range. Non-clustered index on TransactionId.
`TransactionData` also has a non-cluster index in TransactionId, with StateId and Date as included columns,

Our query want to get the last state of each transaction:

```
SELECT
        T.TransactionId,
        LastState.StateId,
        T.StartDate
    FROM Workflow.[Transaction] T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 
            TOP 1 
            StateId 
        FROM Workflow.[TransactionData] td
        WHERE td.TransactionId = t.TransactionId
        ORDER BY [Date] DESC, StateId DESC
    ) LastState
    WHERE   
            @startDate <= t.StartDate 
            AND t.StartDate < @endDate
    ORDER BY T.StartDate asc
```

Using compatibility level 150, and basically the new cardinality operator which was released in 2014, the query takes very long because of VERY wrong estimates, and thus a very bad plan. Index Spool 190M rows. You can see the full plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyHiDurFP).

[image]

If we use the legacy cardinality operator by adding at hint the end of the select:

```
OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'))
```

We get a much better estimation and plan. You can see the full plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByZAIuSYD).
[image]

Seeing this we checked the statistics on both tables, both updated within 1 day.

The problem is even more apparent when running a simple select:

```
 SELECT
        TransactionId
    FROM Workflow.[Transaction]
    where StartDate >= '2020-11-05 00:00:00 +02:00' and 
          StartDate < '2020-11-06 00:00:00 +02:00'
```

[image].

Estimated: 7791, Actual 108855. Query plan can be seen [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1b9r_rKD).
If we enable again the legacy cardinality operator via the HINT, we get a much better estimate: 131315 (82%). New query plan can be seen [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJRSUOHKv).

Gist from cluster index statistics:

```
                Histogram Steps
                    RANGE_HI_KEY                      RANGE_ROWS                         EQ_ROWS             DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS                  AVG_RANGE_ROWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10/27/2020 2:58:32 AM +02:00                        731904.2                               1                          727784                        1.005661
   10/31/2020 12:14:20 PM +02:00                          470738                               1                          468159                        1.005508
     11/6/2020 3:40:41 PM +02:00                        805856.3                               1                          802208                        1.004547
```

Why would the new cardinality operator have such bad estimates on what seems a very trivial case?

Comment: Rather than images, upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question. The actual plan may include details to better answer your question. Note that one can specify the legacy CE as the default using database scoped configuration and retain the 150 database compatibility level. That allows one to opt in for the new CE using a hint instead of opting out.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for your suggestion. I've added links to all query plans. I can "workaround" the issue, but it troubles me that I don't understand why the wrong estimated on a recently updated stats for a simple clustered index.

Comment: The plan for the first query was compiled with date range 2020-11-07 to 2020-11-08 and the cache entry reused for the 2020-11-06 to 2020-11-07 range. That might explain the underestimate in that case since there are probably fewer rows for the current day that the previous day.

Comment: FWIW, I get accurate estimates with both the [legacy CE](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryPq4nrYv) and [new CE](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1qT43HFD) using the simplified queries from your uploaded plans, a transaction table with 1M rows, and one row per second (86,000 rows qualify for a single date). This was with SQL 2019 CU8 rather than MI, though. It could be a fix exists in CU8 that has not been applied to MI yet.

Comment: Thnaks for getting involved @DanGuzman. IRT: "The plan for the first query was compiled with date range 2020-11-07 to 2020-11-08 and the cache entry reused for the 2020-11-06 to 2020-11-07 range. " -- I specifically tried dates in the past for the query because once they are inspected for stats, they would not change any more.  In the stats table we can see 6th, I query 5th of Nov, so in theory it should not matter, i think :) I will try on older dates to see if it changes anything, right now I'm trying to update stats with full scan to see if it changes anything. Good point about CU8!

Comment: Current version is: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Oct  1 2020 18:48:35   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: After updating both table and index stats with full scan, I ran the query with recompile option. The estimates are a bit better, but the plan is better! The query finishes in 3 secs as opposed to 12 minutes. Could the full scan be so important? We do a weekly stats update and let sql server choose the sample rate.  --  New query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hkq0ikIFP

Comment: If I remove the OPTION(RECOMPILE) it goes back the the old disastrous plan ☹

Comment: I was going to suggest the recompile option but you beat me too it. That will optimize for the current param values. This can be a good option as long as the query isn't executed frequently (many times per second), Classic parameter sniffing can happen regardless of the CE,

Comment: And yes, avoiding a full scan of 100M+ rows and the spool is important for performance.

Comment: I tried “DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;” it still generated the bad plan afterwards, so it’s not an issue of cached plan. -- "Classic parameter sniffing can happen regardless of the CE" I thought parameter sniffer applies only to stored procs, I'm issuing plain ad-hoc queries. Hmm replacing the variables with direct values, generates correct plan. Maybe you are write, it's the query params. Be that as it may, what about totally wrong cluster index estimates for the simple select? Thare are no params there..

Comment: Note that in your original queries, both cardinality estimators produced bad (massively high) estimates for **all** of the estimates other than the clustered index scan. I think it is only through luck (and maybe the cross-apply) that the old engine made it do nested loops to seeks on the clustered index. If its estimates were correct, that would be a bad plan to have, which I believe is why the newer CE does a different plan. The data itself is heavily clustered - you may want to consider approaching this a somewhat different way (e.g., split query into two with a temp table).

Comment: Parameter sniffing applies to any parameterized query. The strict definition of ad-hoc query in the SQL Server world is a query with literals instead of parameters. I tested from SSMS using a parametrized query like: `EXEC sp_executesql
  N'select T . TransactionId from Workflow.[Transaction] T where StartDate > = @0 and StartDate < @1  option ( use HINT ( ''FORCE_DEFAULT_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'' ) );'
 ,N'@0 varchar(8000), @1 varchar(8000)'
 ,@0 = '2020-11-05 00:00:00 +02:00', @1='2020-11-06 00:00:00 +02:00';`;

Comment: So I can workaround the parameter sniffing problem. And it seems after updating stats with full scan, the simple tx query `SELECT
        TransactionId
    FROM Workflow.[Transaction]
    where StartDate >= '2020-11-05 00:00:00 +02:00' and 
          StartDate < '2020-11-06 00:00:00 +02:00'` -- returns the correct estimates. 103% as opposed to 1397% initially.

Comment: DanGuzman, seanb. Thanks for joining in on this matter. Your help is greatly appreciated!!